# How can I simplify a block of code using constexpr and auto?

Tags: c++, c++20

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(collection)>)
{
  auto view =
    Ranges::Views::CopyView
      <std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>(collection);
  static_assert(std::input_iterator<decltype(view.begin())>);
  static_assert
    (std::sentinel_for<decltype(view.end()), decltype(view.begin())>);

  return view;
}
else
{
  auto view =
    Ranges::Views::View
      <std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>(collection);
  static_assert(std::input_iterator<decltype(view.begin())>);
  static_assert
    (std::sentinel_for<decltype(view.end()), decltype(view.begin())>);
 
  return view;
}
```

I'd like to move view outside the if block but the type of view is very long. It seems the compiler won't accept an uninitialized declaration, even though it could be inferred. I could specify the full type but it's really long, which is why I'm using auto.

Other than having to duplicate static_assert, I also dislike that I need two return statements. I prefer single-in, single-out functions.

Is there a way I can rewrite this snippet to look closer to this?

```
auto view;
if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(collection)>)
{
  view =
    Ranges::Views::CopyView
      <std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>(collection);
}
else
{
  view =
    Ranges::Views::View
      <std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>(collection);
}

static_assert(std::input_iterator<decltype(view.begin())>);
static_assert
(std::sentinel_for<decltype(view.end()), decltype(view.begin())>);
 
return view;
```

Comment: Short answer - no.   `auto` involves type deduction, and there needs to be some basis to deduce the type.   `auto view` provides no information that allows the compiler to deduce the type required of `view`.    If `View` and `CopyView` are both functions, with same/compatible arguments and return type (you haven't specified) you may be able to do `auto view = std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(collection)> ? Ranges::Views::CopyView<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>(collection) : Ranges::Views::View<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>(collection);`.

Comment: Why not add a typedef for the long ass type?

Comment: @Peter Your inline if condition seems to be missing constexpr. Is there an inline version of it?

Comment: Why have two separately named methods? Why not overload `View` for an lvalue and rvalue type and let the compiler handle the rest?

Comment: You make a good point @JHBonarius

Answer (score 3):

You can use immediately invoked lambda to do this:

```
using T = decltype(collection);

auto view = [&collection] {
  using U = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
  if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T>)
    return Ranges::Views::CopyView<U, ValType>(collection); 
  else
    return Ranges::Views::View<U, ValType>(collection);
}();

static_assert(std::input_iterator<decltype(view.begin())>);
static_assert
  (std::sentinel_for<decltype(view.end()), decltype(view.begin())>);

return view;
```

Comment: This is a good answer too!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a usual case for [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
using view_t = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(collection)>,
    Ranges::Views::CopyView<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>,
    Ranges::Views::View<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>
>;

view_t view(collection);
static_assert(std::input_iterator<decltype(view.begin())>);
static_assert(std::sentinel_for<decltype(view.end()), decltype(view.begin())>);
return view;
```

Or, if this is done multiple times or there are lots of template arguments, potentially a little tidier with a small helper:

```
template<template<typename ...> typename T>
struct template_c {
    template<typename ...Px>
    using bind = T<Px...>;
};

// ...

using view_t = typename std::conditional_t<
    std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(collection)>,
    template_c<Ranges::Views::CopyView>,
    template_c<Ranges::Views::View>
>::bind<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(collection)>, ValType>;

view_t view(collection);
// ...
```